# Odoo record rule based on previous value

Tags: odoo, record-rules

I need to create Odoo Record Rules to make sure a state field progressing according to allowed step.

```
allow => 'approved_by+manager' > 'approved_by_senior_manager'
denny => 'approved_by_manager' > 'approved_by_finance'
```

How to create such rule on Odoo Record Rules?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. Please clarify your question.

Comment: what do you mean is this values of you state field? and you want when you update the sequence to be in this order? `approved_by+manager` is it typing error or a real value?

Answer (score 0):

You can add record rule according to particular action like only write operation perform by particular group. You can set domain one according to the previous state(Consider one step before). Like you can set read record rule and they can see only that records.